# GKE: Misunderstanding of values displayed in cpu quota

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-compute-engine

I have launched 2 kubernetes clusters with standard GKE.
The first one is in Switzerland (europe-west6) and the second one in Australia (australia-southeast1). These two clusters are made up of 5 and 3 nodes respectively, representing a total of 32 vCPUs. I don't use any other Google Cloud services. However, in the quota screen (CPU all-region), it shows that 68 CPUs are currently in use, so I'm getting dangerously close to the maximum CPU all-region quota limit for my project.

I searched the Google Cloud documentation, without success.

How to explain these 68 CPUs?

[image: Kubernetes clusters metadata]

[image: CPU quota]

Comment: Did you check reservations?

Comment: Yes but I don't reach such a CPU value

Comment: i would check scaling on gke next as Sai mentionned

Comment: Perhaps break it down per region/zone and see where issue might be coming from (at the quota page). I also wonder whether live migrations are messing the values you are seeing. Does the 68 eventually go down?

Comment: The CPU quota per region looks fine as I get the same values as those displayed in gke. It only affect global GPU quotas. I searched for other regions but only europe-west6 and australia-southeast1 is being used.

Comment: Go to menu > billing > linked billing account > view report and group by SKU and check where the charges are coming from. Grab the SKU n plug in https://cloud.google.com/skus/ and check

Comment: The charges seem correct and do not correspond at all to the value displayed in the quotas (all regions)

Comment: then maybe a display error at google.open a ticket

Comment: Is it free to open a ticket?

Comment: I believe only billing is free. Since it might be a gcp issue perhaps try your luck here https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you verify that you are not utilizing an autoscaler cluster ? Because these tools scale deployments automatically, consuming quotas as they go.

If you deploy workloads without setting resource values such as CPU and memory, Autoscaler cluster automatically resizes the number of nodes in a given node pool, based on the demands of your workloads.

I believe you can view the resources consumed by your application more accurately by checking the quota page.

In order to resolve CPU quota problems, the general recommendation is to use twice as many CPUs as you can. You'll need to request a [quota increase](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6075746?hl=en)  and in your case, that would be about 160 vCPUs. You should confirm that both your E2 CPU quota (which is likely fine) and your total CPU quota (the one in your image) are set.

If you are not using any auto-scaling and autopilot then  [Contact support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub) for assistance.

Comment: I'm using GKE standard mode without any auto-scaling enabled.

Comment: However, there are a number of reasons for this. The GKE metadata server is annotated and sets resource limitations that guarantee it is last in line for eviction If multiple Pods are set to launch simultaneously, this might occur. You can use the [troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting#insufficient_resources) instructions to resolve this and there is a chances of  display error also try to contact [support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub)

Comment: Did you have time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your problem . [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)